# Understanding a statistic sentence

Tags: standard-deviation

I don't know if this question will be clear but i'm irritated by a non-understanding a sentence in a research paper of Alet, Bonnal and Favar (2013) : "Medicine for Short-Run Remission". It's a paper about the effect of repeating class in short-run, medium-run or long-run school achievements.

When the authors present the results (of estimation of the parameters), they tell something like : "the estimated parameter is [...], which corresponds to an improvement of achievement of **52 percent of a standard deviation**. And I can't undestand this (in bold) even after investigations.

It's the reason of my help demand here. 
Hope I was clear. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From table 1: 3rd grade test score is: mean(sd)=67.16(14.87).

From Table 7: impact of retention in 1st grade on 3rd grade test score is mean(sd)=7.76(1.03)

So the mean impact of retention in 1st grade (7.76) is 52% of the standard deviation (sd) of 3rd score grades (14.87), because 7.76/14.87=0.5219.

Comment: if you agree and my answer was useful pls accept it!

Comment: it's the explanation i searched for i think. On the other hand i'm a statistician / econometrician neophyte so all i can do for now is to accept your clear answer !

Comment: However I detected a problem with this a minute ago : for the impact of R in 6th grade test score (-5.13) from table 7, and the std of 6th grade test score from table 1 (16.16), -5.13/16.16 = - 32% but not -38% as stated in the paper. And i noted that they said that the effect of R on 6th grade test score is -6 (quite far from -5.13), but still it's not working because -6/16/16 = 37% but not 38% as said in the paper. I'm a little confused, but I think your answer is the explanation

Comment: I agree this is inconsistent. I think they might have taken 6.2 (impact of R on males instead as on the whole sample) from table 1 instead of 5.13. this single mistake might explain it all. however, who knows. why don't you write the authors pointing out this inconsistency?

Comment: It's have been already done but i didn't get any answer